# Should we add a reason for closing questions that are discussions?

Tags: discussion

Should we add a reason for closing questions that are discussions, or that try to seek discussion?

"primarily opinion-based" may sometimes not work.

Here's a suggested reason, right from the help center:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. [Chatty, open-ended
>   questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) diminish
>   the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front
>   page.

(thanks @5chdn for idea)

Example:

[Ethereum and bullying and possible coersion to delete by third parties](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/ethereum-and-bullying-and-possible-coersion-to-delete-by-third-parties)

[Is a hardfork more democratic then a softfork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/is-a-hardfork-more-democtratic-then-a-softfork)

Whatever answer gets posted, the asker will probably discuss in comments (as they've done)...

EDIT:

Another example: 
[Is the DAO incident being investigated by law enforcement?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/is-the-dao-incident-being-investigated-by-law-enforcement)

There are questions that may "trap" answerers into giving an opinion or primarily opinion-based answer.  This meta discussion is about how to deal with those questions, because even an "agreeable, logically defendable answer" can still attract debates and further discussions...

Answer (score 4):

I feel that primarily opinion based is already a good answer. If something has no agreeable, logically defendable answer then it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: Some things can have an agreeable, defendable answer but perhaps very narrowly...  For example, this could have http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/is-the-dao-incident-being-investigated-by-law-enforcement